# 'list' object has no attribute 'encode

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

Can somebody help me?

i want to attach a excel file for an email sender in python but gives everytime an error. I looked online and everywhere it said it like it is in my code. can somebody tell me whats wrong

thank you verry much

```
 message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['Subject'] = 'Maandelijks rapport'
    message['To'] = receiver_email
    message['From'] = sender_email
    message.attach(MIMEText('In de bijlage vind je het maandrapport terug!'))

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open('test.xls', "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Desposition', 'attachment; filename="test.xls"')
    message.attach(part)


    #send the email 


    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(sender_email, password)
        print('connecting with smtp server...')

        smtp.login(sender_email, password)

       

        smtp.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string())
        print('connection succeed!')
        print('email has been sent!')

        smtp.quit()
```

Comment: IndentationError - please fix by [edit]ing

Comment: +Add the complete stacktrace of your error as well - I am not sure where you call `encode` in the shown code - I only see `encoders.encode_base64(part)`. Whatever you call `whatever.encode(..)` with is a list - and lists do not have that method.